# Numerical solutions PDES finite difference scheme leap Frog derive the scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

[image]

I need help with part 3 of this question, I cannot derive this scheme no matter what I try!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to write out what you already try.

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$? Is that part of the problem where you need to determine $f$ and $g$?

Comment: NO, I have edited the question to make f an g clearer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite Difference scheme -Leap Frog](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250366/finite-difference-scheme-leap-frog)